# Aren't both of these conditions the same?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving this beginner problem on Codeforces, Young Physicist.
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A

The answer is to find if 3 forces are in equilibrium.

I've submitted two versions of my answers. One passed but one didn't. But I can't figure why it won't pass, aren't both of the condition same?

```
if (sumx == 0 && sumy == 0 && sumz == 0)
    cout << "YES" << "\n";
else
    cout << "NO" << "\n";
```

above is the one that passed.

```
if (sumx + sumy + sumz == 0)
    cout << "YES" << "\n";
else
    cout << "NO" << "\n";
```

this is the one that didn't pass.

Comment: Assume `sumx == -2`, `sumy == 1`, `sumz == 1`, so these conditions are not the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider `sumx = -1`, `sumy = 1`, `sumz = 0`. There's a 2-dimensional infinity of solutions to `x + y + z = 0`, and `x = y = z = 0` is just a 0-dimensional singularity.

If you graph `x + y + z = 0`, you get this:

[image: a plane representing the solutions]

Every point on this plane is a set of three values that gives you 0 from their sum. The point where all three are zero is just a single point out of the sea. A quick check that tells you you've oversimplified the constraint is that you have 3 variables, but only 1 equation. That means you should still have 3 - 1 = 2 dimensions of freedom, but a single point has 0 dimensions of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. When you have `sumx + sumy + sumz == 0`, it doesn't necessarily mean that all these variables are equal to 0. Let's assume that `sumx = -1`, `sumy = 0`, `symz = 1`. This:

```cpp
if (sumx == 0 && sumy == 0 && sumz == 0)
    cout << "YES" << "\n";
else
    cout << "NO" << "\n";
```

outputs `NO`, but this:

```cpp
if (sumx + sumy + sumz == 0)
    cout << "YES" << "\n";
else
    cout << "NO" << "\n";
```

outputs `YES`.